# Knockoutjs model does not update when select options change

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a computed function which doesn't update the UI when a select options change. But works fine if I add or remove a line.

This is the HTML:

```
<button data-bind="click: add">Add New</button>
<ul data-bind="foreach: items">
    <li>
        <label data-bind="text: name"></label>
        <select data-bind="options: [1,2,3], value: val"> </select>
    </li>
</ul>
TOTAL: <span data-bind="text: total"></span>
```

And this the JavaScritp:

```
function viewModel (initialItems) {
    this.items = ko.observableArray(initialItems);

    this.total = ko.computed(function () {
        var total = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < this.items().length; i++)
            total += this.items()[i].val;
        return total;
    }, this);

    this.add = function() { this.items.push({name: "New", val: 1}); };
}

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel([{name: "Alpha", val: 2}, 
                                  {name: "Beta", val: 3},
                                  {name: "Gamma", val: 1}]));
```

And here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/waUE4/

How can I get the model update when selection change?

Thanks for your help.

**Edit**

Working version: http://jsfiddle.net/fCE3a/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why the `val` property is not updated is that it is not declared as an `Observable` property.

Check out this sample code from the official KnockoutJS website, it looks like what you want to do: [Cart editor example](http://knockoutjs.com/examples/cartEditor.html)